# Hide existing YouTube comments from Google+ Posts

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I've been using YouTube and Google+ for years now. In the past I've posted comments on YouTube videos with little restraint. Now, unfortunately, my Google+ feed is an embarrassing window into the mind of 16-year-old me.

I don't necessarily want to remove all the comments, but I would like to hide them from my Google+ feed. Is there an easy way to do that? Keep in mind, there's thousands, if not tens of thousands of posts. I also wish to keep posting comments on YouTube videos publicly, but without them appearing on my feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [Google+ Settings](https://plus.google.com/settings) » Profile and uncheck 'Show these profile tabs to visitors » Youtube/Videos':

[image: screenshot of settings described above]

You can also modify this setting in [Google's Privacy Checkup](https://myaccount.google.com/privacycheckup/?hl=en) page (among other Google-related privacy settings).